# Zabbix cannot send list of active checks

Tags: linux, zabbix

Good afternoon. Help please understand. There is Zabbix v2.08

I got my hands on duty tuned zabbix from another administrator. I have it cleaned and put in order. Everything works, but I can see the agent logs a permanent record - can not send list of active checks to [1.2.3.4]: host [superhost] not found.

In the setting of an agent on the server zabbix no such mention. Just do not understand the situation. 1.2.3.4 (testhost) is not superhost, a superhost is 1.2.3.10

Help please understand

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lines like "cannot send list of active checks to ..." are not logged by the agent - they are logged by the server when it receives a request for a list of active checks from an agent. In these requests, the agent specifies its hostname ("Hostname" parameter in the configuration file). If the server cannot find such a host in its database, it logs this error message.

So you should check the "Hostname" parameter in agent configuration file and verify that there exists a host with this name in server's database.

Comment: tnx. restart agent also needed.

Comment: I am getting the error on the client: `no active checks on server [<ip>:10051]: host [<hostname>] not found`

Comment: @kev, as the error message says, please verify that the hostname in the agent configuration file matches a hostname in the frontend exactly.

Comment: I am using Auto registration to submit the hostname to the server. Is it possible, that the client talks to the server before the server actually know who it is talking to?

Comment: We may be getting a bit off-topic here, but do you have auto-registration working correctly (https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/discovery/auto_registration)? Do you have a corresponding action defined and do you have new hosts created automatically?